# Beginner, .net C# using Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying for days to be able to use a database with a simple web base .net project.
I successfully followed a tutorial using SQL compact, but it was suggested that I use SQLEXPRESS because it creates .mdf files, sames as VISUAL STUDIO.

Out of frustration, I have reinstalled clean copy of:
Windows 10
Visual Studio Community 2015
SQL Server Express(2014). Note: would not start unless log on as: set to built in account, Local System. This an issue?

Here is my code:
[CODE]

```
@using WebMatrix.Data; 
@using System.Data.SqlClient


@{ 



}

@{
var Name = "";
var Position = "";
var Department = "";
var Shift = "";

if (IsPost)
{



    Name = Request.Form["Name"];
    Position = Request.Form["Position"];
    Department = Request.Form["Department"];
    Shift = Request.Form["Shift"];

    String ConnStr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=\"C: \\Users\\Tevis Cox\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\TutorialPages\\TutorialPages\\App_Data\\devDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeName, Position, Department, Shift) VALUES("+ Name + "," + Position + "," + Department +"," + Shift + ")";
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }


}
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Add Personnel</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add Personnel</h1>
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personnel Information</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" value="@Request.Form["Name"]" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="Position">Position:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Position" value="@Request.Form["Position"]" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="Department">Department:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Department" value="@Request.Form["Department"]" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Shift">Shift:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Shift" value="@Request.Form["Shift"]" />
        </p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Add" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[/CODE]
Yes, I know this is vulnerable to sql injection attack. it will be addressed.

The current error with this setup says that the login failed. This is after I connected to the DB with SQL Server Management Studio. Prior to connecting with the management studio it would complain that there was a db of the same name there.

If you know an easy tutorial, please point me to it.

Comment: Looks like your database isn't set up to use integrated security, or your Windows account doesn't have access.  Is there a logon and password you can use instead?  Also, when you fix that, your query won't work since none of the values are quoted.  Maybe start with a simple `SELECT * FROM Employees` instead.

Comment: `"The current error with this setup says that the login failed."` - I don't see anything in this code which would produce that message.  (Unless the message is coming from the database itself?  Please specify.)  I do see a bug in your `INSERT` statement, though.  You're passing string values, but aren't enclosing those values in quotes.

Answer (score -1):

This code works:

```
@using WebMatrix.Data; 
@using System.Data.SqlClient


@{ 



}

@{
var Name = "";
var Position = "";
var Department = "";
var Shift = "";

if (IsPost)
{



    Name = Request.Form["Name"];
    Position = Request.Form["Position"];
    Department = Request.Form["Department"];
    Shift = Request.Form["Shift"];

    String ConnStr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Tevis Cox\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\TutorialPages\\TutorialPages\\App_Data\\devDB.mdf; Database=\"asdfdevDB\"; User ID=tcox; Password=123; Integrated Security=True;";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeName, Position, Department, Shift) VALUES(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p1", Name));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p2", Position));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p3", Department));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p4", Shift));


        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }


}
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Add Personnel</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add Personnel</h1>
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personnel Information</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" value="@Request.Form["Name"]" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="Position">Position:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Position" value="@Request.Form["Position"]" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="Department">Department:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Department" value="@Request.Form["Department"]" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Shift">Shift:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Shift" value="@Request.Form["Shift"]" />
        </p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Add" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```